# How can I make a portable thumb drive with apps that would work with Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, portable

So, my situation is as follows, during my weekly routine I have to transition between several computers, work, college plus home-laptop, work-laptop and sometimes sister's laptop.

In college in special I'll might end up with a different computer on a daily basis,  and while we have some tools necessary, it becomes a common chore to install Git and some IDE I need to actually get work done.

Yesterday I decided to make a portable generic thumb drive.

I quickly added some portable apps I always need, like Git, Dev-Cpp and notepad++.

I realized that it'd be nice to have a portable app thumb drive could work in Linux AND Windows, specially because I could have my personal favourite terminal in Linux perfectly configured, and have my Windows Git Bash with its own configuration - but maybe both might call some specific git settings, like proxy.

So, is it possible to have files that would run in a linux distro AND files that would run in a windows os without partitioning the drive?

Comment: any progress on the problem/solution?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you just have to make sure you use a partition format that can be accessed by both OS. Either by for example using FAT which can be accessed natively by both OS or if - for example - you want to use NTFS you need to make sure that you're integrating the capability to read/write NTFS into your Linux (in this case you'll need [additional software](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access) for write access).

Comment: Please consider leaving a suggestion on how to improve the answer when downvoting, thank you.